# What was the fireball that Naru saw from the tree top when she was battling the lion?

Tags: plot-explanation, predator, prey

In Prey (2022), the main protagonist, Naru had to lure a mountain lion into an ambush. In a turn of event, Naru got pin down by the lion and had to resort to climb a tree.

From the tree top she saw what looks like a fireball in the tree line in the distance which distracted here causing the lion maul her and she fell from the tree. No further explanation of what she saw. Later, she did mention to her brother that she saw something but did not elaborate more.

What was it that she saw? Was it the Predator doing?

Answer (score 2):

> What was it that she saw? Was it the Predator doing?

We don't know BUT it's almost certain it is the Predator firing it's weapon or causing it somehow.

Exactly what remains unanswered. I'm trying to find a copy of the script but without much luck.

There is something similar when the Predator is killing the French hunters.

[image]

Comment: It is really hard to see. They reference to it firing its weapon, but to me it just looked like a campfire or something, wasn't really discernible to me.

Comment: It's definitely an explosion of some kind or a large flare up at least. The logical explanation, given what we know, or find out later, is that it's the Predator weaponry. I'll re-watch to double check.

Comment: maybe its my crap monitor or tv then, just looked really dull and not 'pew pew' or boom like...

Comment: There's definitely a sound associated with the flare which seemed familiar.

Comment: Yeah its kind of a roar in the distance. I guess I 'know' its supposed to be the Predator, but it doesn't feel 'enough' to be much of anything. I think thats just me though.

Comment: On rewatch the Predator doesn't seem to have any advanced laser weaponry such as we saw in previous movies. I still think it was the Predator but what it was doing is open to question.

Comment: That said, when the Predator is killing the French hunters it does use a remote weapon that seems to have the same red flare look in the fog.

Comment: When I re-watched  the movie i was thinking the flare was a campfire. Since the audience is given clue there's adversary other than the Predator (i.e. the trappers) with the scene with skinned bison, the iron trap, i was thinking this is also one of the clue.